# InputAccessoryView with custom view created in IB

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, inputaccessoryview

I've read a lot of material on this topic but most of them create custom view programatically.

Is it possible to use InputAccessoryView with a custom view created in IB? In storyboard I've added textInputView, inside which I've added text view and send button etc as seen in the screenshot below.

I've following code so which **removes Table View** for some reason so I can't get it working. I've added tableview in the storyboard.

I've shown here only InputAccessoryView related code.

```
class InputAccViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textInputView: UIView!
    // other code

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { return true }

    override var inputAccessoryView:UIView {
       get{
           return self.textInputView
       }
   }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textInputView.removeFromSuperview()
        // other code
    }
     // other code tableview delegates etc...
}
```

Left screenshot is with the accessory view code which doesn't show table view. If I comment out accessory view related code it does show table view as in the right screenshot.

[image]

Comment: And the tableView shows without the input accessory view?

Comment: It show the inputTextView as you can see in the screenshot. Entering in text view does show up keyboard. Since tableview doesn't show I can't check drag to dismiss feature. I'm not sure why table view doesn't show after adding code for accessory view? If I remove accessory view table view shows up.

Comment: What happens if you remove this line :    'textInputView.removeFromSuperview()' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you might be constraining the `UITableView`'s bottom to the `textInputView`'s top. When you are setting the `textInputView` as the `inputAccessoryView` of the `UIViewController` this no longer works as expected. When setting the `textInputView` as the `inputAccessoryView` make sure you constraint the bottom of `UITableView` to the bottom of `UIViewController`'s `view`.

Comment: I had to take a few guesses to figure this out. It would be better if you provided more details regarding your implementation when posting a new question in the future.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was constraint issue otherwise I would have added more details as required.